# Creating Diagram from Excel Using VB

Tags: vba, excel, csv, visio

Sorry I can't embed images, I have the links instead (... I can only post two links. I have removed the http:// substring from   some of the links).

I am looking to take an .csv file (really, any file, as I am generating this myself), and create a Visio (2010) diagram out of it. I have successfully imported the excel sheet to Visio, and can create some rough diagrams, but they are not enough. This is what I'm trying to [create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOEr4.jpg). Here are the following tactics I have tried, I prefer the VB method, but whatever works works:

**Data Graphics:** This is the closest I've gotten to a solution. Basically you create shapes and you can put data in it. Problem is, the style of display available are limited, as we can see here (imgur.com/clTLcxk). After importing the excel sheet, all I had to do was drag and drop to create these shapes. The closest I have gotten is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSRin.jpg). However, I really need the outside box (or container, for aesthetic reasons). (Some information here [support.office.com/en-us/article/Enhance-your-data-with-data-graphics-45af64a4-1dcb-4463-9a7e-67709786181c])

**VB:** I have been using this (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff959245%28v=office.14%29.aspx). I have ran some of the example code, but I am really lost. I have run some of the example code but the only one I have really gotten to work are useless to me. Also, I don't see any API methods that actually add data to these diagrams!

So how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by first defining or finding Visio masters that would the data I'm drawing to the page.  In your case it looks like you'd want a master for your Foo items, and one for your Bar items.

So then you'd step through your Bars, then within each Bar you'd have one or more Foos.  For each Foo, you would drop that master out, and set the text of the shape to what you want in the blue Foo section (maybe a grouped sub-shape for the Foo master), and then text in the white body.

When stepping through all the Bars, you'd obviously have to drop out a Bar shape and position/size it to contain all the Foos.